# Publishing Azure Function from VS 2017 does not create csx file

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created a simple Azure Function using VS 2017 to test the tooling.

This is the project:

[image]

Here is the publish screen:

[image: Publish screen in VS 2017]

Clicking on Publish button does not show any progress but I can see the new Function at the Portal.
However the published Function has only the function.json and no csx file.

[image: In Portal]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design. VS2017 (15.3) won't create `csx` script, but instead will deploy your code as precompiled function. You can tell that precompiled function is used by looking at `scriptFile` and `entryPoint` attributes in your `function.json`.

By the way, `Publish` result can be seen in `Output` tab of Visual Studio.

Comment: So, Should I just not deploy using Visual studio? Or I Should I uncheck precompile function ? Whats the idea behind csx script?

Comment: @JamshaidKamran You can use Visual Studio. `csx` was the initial approach to developing Azure Functions. Now, the precompiled functions are the way to go. Just don't expect to see `csx` files in the portal after publishing from VS or func CLI.

Comment: Shikov Okay, Got that point. So, How can I added my `.exe` files after I have deployed using Visual Studio. As I see they disable the upload feature after it has been published?